# Moq no invocations performed on 2nd Verify

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, nunit, moq

I am using NUnit and Moq to test some simple classes.

When I run the test it fails on the second moq verify check. What's strange is that I have done exactly the same thing in a similar class and it works fine. I have looked for similar issues but only seem to find answers for returning an async Task.

If I swap the order of the method calls I'm testing in the actual class so that the PushAsync method is called first then it's the PostStats verify that fails.
This would make me think it can only do one verify but I've done two in my other test fine (both with the same return types).

The error I get is:

```
Message: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ExerciseNotes>())

Configured setups: 
IPageService p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ExerciseNotes>())
No invocations performed
```

Here is my class:

```
 public class ExerciseRatingViewModel
{
    public int DifficultyRating { get; set; }
    public int PainRating { get; set; }
    public int MobilityRating { get; set; }
    public ICommand SubmitRatingsCommand { get; }

    private readonly IPageService _pageService;
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    private readonly IAPIService _apiService;

    private int _sequenceID;

    public ExerciseRatingViewModel(int sequenceID, IPageService pageService, IDataService dataService, IAPIService apiService)
    {
        _sequenceID = sequenceID;
        _pageService = pageService;
        _dataService = dataService;
        _apiService = apiService;
        SubmitRatingsCommand = new Command(SubmitStats);
    }

    private async void SubmitStats()
    {
        int userID = _dataService.GetUserID();
        SequenceRating sequenceRating = new SequenceRating(_sequenceID, userID, DifficultyRating, PainRating, MobilityRating);
        bool success = await _apiService.PostStats(sequenceRating);
        await _pageService.PushAsync(new ExerciseNotes());
    }      
}
```

Here is my Test Class

```
class ExerciseRatingViewModelTests
{
    private ExerciseRatingViewModel _exerciseRatingViewModel;
    private Mock<IPageService> _pageService;
    private Mock<IDataService> _dataService;
    private Mock<IAPIService> _apiService;


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _pageService = new Mock<IPageService>();
        _dataService = new Mock<IDataService>();
        _apiService = new Mock<IAPIService>();
        int sequenceID = 1;
        _exerciseRatingViewModel = new ExerciseRatingViewModel(sequenceID, _pageService.Object, _dataService.Object, _apiService.Object);
    }

    [Test()]
    public void SubmitStats_WhenTouched_ShouldNavigateToNotesPage()
    {

        //Arrange
        _apiService.Setup(a => a.PostStats(It.IsAny<SequenceRating>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
        _pageService.Setup(p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ExerciseNotes>()));


        // Act
        _exerciseRatingViewModel.SubmitRatingsCommand.Execute(null);

        //Assert
        _apiService.Verify(a => a.PostStats(It.IsAny<SequenceRating>()));
        _pageService.Verify(p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ExerciseNotes>()));
    }
}
```

The signature for the PostStats method is:

```
 Task<bool> PostStats(SequenceRating sequenceRating);
```

The signature for the PushAsync method is:

```
 Task PushAsync(Page page);
```

Comment: You are working with `Task` so the test would need to be async and also the mock would need to return a `Task` to allow for the async to flow as expected. You already did it for `PostStats`. Now just do the same for `PushAsync`

Comment: avoid `async void` except for event handlers.

Comment: It makes things a little more tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First refactor view model to avoid `async void` functions, except for actual event handlers

```
public ExerciseRatingViewModel(int sequenceID, IPageService pageService, IDataService dataService, IAPIService apiService) {
    _sequenceID = sequenceID;
    _pageService = pageService;
    _dataService = dataService;
    _apiService = apiService;
    submitted += onSubmitted; //subscribe to event
    SubmitRatingsCommand = new Command(() => submitted(null, EventArgs.Empty));
}

private event EventHandler submitted = delegate { };
private async void onSubmitted(object sender, EventArgs args) { //event handler
    await SubmitStats();
}

private async Task SubmitStats() {
    int userID = _dataService.GetUserID();
    SequenceRating sequenceRating = new SequenceRating(_sequenceID, userID, DifficultyRating, PainRating, MobilityRating);
    bool success = await _apiService.PostStats(sequenceRating);
    await _pageService.PushAsync(new ExerciseNotes());
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

You are working with `Task` so the test would need to be async and also the mock would need to return a `Task` to allow for the async to flow as expected. You already did it for `PostStats`. Now just do the same for `PushAsync`.

```
[Test()]
public async Task SubmitStats_WhenTouched_ShouldNavigateToNotesPage() {
    //Arrange
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    _apiService.Setup(a => a.PostStats(It.IsAny<SequenceRating>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
    _pageService.Setup(p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<Page>()))
        .Callback((Page arg) => tcs.SetResult(null))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));

    // Act
    _exerciseRatingViewModel.SubmitRatingsCommand.Execute(null);

    await tcs.Task; //wait for async flow to complete

    //Assert
    _apiService.Verify(a => a.PostStats(It.IsAny<SequenceRating>()));
    _pageService.Verify(p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ExerciseNotes>()));
}
```

In the test, a `TaskCompletionSource` is used in a callback of the mock in order to allow for the awaiting of the async code to be completed before trying to verify behavior. This is done because of the events and the command that are executing on separate threads.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have refactored my code as you suggested. It does not seem to work quite right though as the Tests never finish running.

Comment: @HenryJ ok let me recheck the code. I would also suggest putting some breakpoints in the event handlers to make sure they are being invoked.

Comment: I should mention that the application works fine with the code you provided, it's just the test doesn't ever finish

Comment: Thank you for your update to the code but the test still doesn't finish running. I had to change the callback type from an ExerciseNotes object to a Page as that's the base class the service takes as an argument. I've tried a few different things but I just can't seem to get it working

Comment: @HenryJ I've just spent some time recreating all the code you have presented so far and ran it in a unit test that passes as expected when exercised with the details from the answer I provided (including the change with Page)

Comment: @HenryJ the only way I was able to get the problem you were experiencing was to comment out the callback that allowed the completion source result to be set. I suggest you review the provided answer again and make sure you are following it as presented.

Comment: thank you for your help. The reason my callback was never executed is because the Mocked service was silently erroring out due to the ExerciseNotes class trying to access a static Xamarin resource. I appreciate your patience with my issue, thanks again.